# AWS SDK for S3 only

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have add the following dependencies to allow me to access S3 bucket from within Java application

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And I found it downloaded 53 jar files which add up to 21 MB, this is a bit insane. Is there a smaller package allows me to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package you are looking for is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Or the latest version which now is `1.10.54`. See the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.10.54) for more details.

Comment: Note that the core package another user mentioned in his answer is downloaded automatically as a dependency of the S3 SDK package.

Comment: I navigate to the location of the aws-java-sdk-s3 pom file in my console, then I type "mvn clean install" and hit enter. However, the resulting `jar` file (found in the "target" folder in the "aws-java-sdk-s3" folder) does not include the "core" package, despite the fact that the s3 pom file specifies it as a dependency (identical to: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/pom.xml). Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

If you look at the [Maven Repository Listing for their group](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws), I think you want the "AWS SDK For Java Core" and "AWS Java SDK For Amazon S3", but you might need an authentication/credentials one, too - I can't remember if that's in the core one or not.